# Redirecting Servlet to Unicode-Domains

Tags: java, redirect, character-encoding, servlets

I'm having problems with sending redirections to servlet with Unicode-URLs.

i.e. consider the following url in Turkish

> [http://türkçeisimtescil.com](http://t%C3%BCrk%C3%A7eisimtescil.com)

It works if you paste it into your browser's address bar. However it is translated to

> http://xn--trkeisimtescil-ijb74a.com

by your browser upon your request.

Let's say I have first URL with UTF8-specific chars and I get it successfully from DB. I want to redirect my servlet to that URL.

However when I just do `response.sendRedirect(url);` (according to headers) it redirects me to `www.t%1frk%e7eisimtescil.com`

I tried even `response.sendRedirect("http://www.t\u011Frk\u00E7eisimtescil.com");` (inline encoding) and the response is exactly the same.

Maybe if I obtain türkçeisimtescil.com on the headers, browser will convert it to `xn--..` format and it will succeed.

I could not figure out where the encoding got broken. Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an [Internationalized Domain Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (IDN). Its conversion between [ASCII and Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode) is specified in [RFC 3490](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode). In Java, you can use [`java.net.IDN`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html) to convert between the one and other. You can use [`java.net.URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) to obtain the host part from the URL.

```
String host = new URL("http://türkçeisimtescil.com").getHost();
String idn = IDN.toASCII(host);
String newURL = "http://" + idn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

IDN class of `java.net.IDN` solves this by obtaining "ponycode" (xn--.. ) URLs.

```
java.net.IDN.toASCII(url)
```

3 self-answering in a row ftw :)

Comment: You're quick! Note that you'd like to convert only the domain (host) part. See my answer.

Comment: Actually I need the whole url (authority, port, querystring, domain) to convert. Of course IDN ponycode should apply just on domain. I am looking for a convenient solution because it does something like xn--http://..  which is unexpected (by me). Any ideas?

Comment: Interestingly it generates a `http://xn--` for `http://A.türkçe` or `http://w.türkçe` very well but `xn--http://` for `http://türkçeblabla...` pulling my hair out.

Comment: Simply here's the problem:

    `String idn = IDN.toASCII("http://türkçeisimtescil.com");
    System.out.println(idn);`

generates a `xn--http:// which` is wrong. I should convert only the domain without losing anything in `authentication:data@and:port/orFile?plus=querystrings#and_refs`